# how to upgrade Node.js 12.22.9 version to latest version node 18.17.1 in Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js

Some times I get errors that I need to upgrade or not supported npm for current node or vice versa. And says that you need to upgrade to that version.

I tried brew. And installed Node.js and again I get install Node.js version 12.22.9 and npm version 9.6.3.

How can I upgrade Node.js and npm versions to the latest versions Node 20.5.1 (including npm 9.8.0)?

Answer (score 1):

I did this

```
sudo apt --auto-remove purge npm 

sudo apt --auto-remove purge nodejs
```

and then reinstall node

Comment: First of All I installed brew using command in ubuntu and then brew install node and then above two commands did the trick

Comment: (Prefer `edit` over `add comment` when the additional information improves the post for most readers.)